# $\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k2^k}{k+1}}{2^n}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Determine
> $$\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k2^k}{k+1}}{2^n}\text{.}$$

For large even $n$,
\begin{aligned}
0&\leq1+\left(-\frac{2}{2}+\frac{4}{3}\right)+\cdots+\left(-\frac{2^{n-1}}{n}+\frac{2^n}{n+1}\right)\\
&=\left(1-\frac{2}{2}\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac{2^{n-2}}{n-1}-\frac{2^{n-1}}{n}\right)+\frac{2^n}{n+1}\leq\frac{2^n}{n+1},
\end{aligned}
so that $\frac{\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k2^k}{k+1}}{2^n}\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow0$. Similarly, for large odd $n$, $\frac{\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k2^k}{k+1}}{2^n}\rightarrow0$ and $\frac{\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k2^k}{k+1}}{2^n}<0$. Thus the series converges.

Since
$$\sum^\infty_{k=0}\sum^\infty_{n=k}\frac{1}{(k+1)2^{n-k}}=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{2}{k+1}$$
diverges, we cannot simply say $\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k2^k}{k+1}}{2^n}=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k2}{k+1}$.

How to find the sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the series $\displaystyle{\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}}$ is convergent and the series $\displaystyle{\sum \frac{1}{2^n}}$ is absolutely convergent, then the Cauchy product of these two series is well-defined and one has
\begin{align*}
\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k2^k}{k+1}}{2^n} & =\sum^\infty_{n=0}\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)2^{n-k}}\\
&=\left( \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \right)
\end{align*}

which gives directly that

$$\boxed{\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k2^k}{k+1}}{2^n} = 2 \log(2)}$$

Comment: How did you notice that it can be written as a Cauchy product of two series?

Comment: Well, the "$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n ...$" and the fact that the $2^n$ and the $2^k$ can be put together are good clues.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should work,
Write,
$$\frac1{k+1}=\int_{0}^{1}x^{k}\,dx$$
And bring the summation sign inside and see that alternating geometric series for finite terms. Try by bringing the integral outside the summation for $n\geq0$ and see if any simplifications are possible.